# What polynomial theorem was used here?

Tags: polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

I was going through a proof and couldn't understand this part about homogeneous symmetric polynomials.

> $$x^4(y − z) + y^4(z − x) + z^4(x − y) = −(x − y)(y − z)(z − x) $$
>
> Viewing the left-hand side as a polynomial in x, the zeros of the polynomial are y and z, and
> its coefficients are divisible by y − z. Hence there is a quadratic homogeneous symmetric
> polynomial Q(x, y, z) such that
>
> $$ x^4
> (y − z) + y^4
> (z − x) + z^4
> (x − y) = (x − y)(y − z)(z − x)Q(x, y,z) $$

I know what a homogeneous symmetric polynomial is, but I was suspecting that there was some kind of underlying theorem used that wasn't outlined explicitly.

[Excerpt from textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvH4m.png)

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not otherwise present in your post. [Here is an explanation why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: What is the textbook?

Comment: Putnam and Beyond by Gelca and Andreescu

Comment: I have the book but cannot find your question. What page?

Comment: Page 50, the example problem in section 2.2.2

Comment: I have the first edition...